# Automated cloud function only sometimes performs update

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-app-engine, cron, cloud

We have a React.js web application for one of our clients. The client has thousands of customers, and each customer makes payments/transactions every couple of months. The web application is developed using React and node, and is deployed using `firebase-cli`. In order to process transactions, we work with a 3rd party vendor (a credit card processing company) who supplies us with a Transaction Report REST API.

The issue is arising with our cloud function that is deployed to Firebase. This cloud function runs every night at 11:50PM EST, using Google Cloud cron jobs as the automation tool. The function makes a call out to the REST API using axios, and when a payload response is returned, our logic iterates through the response. The logic in this function gathers data from each transaction *(e.g. custom Account Number, name, address, payment amount, etc.)* and updates the history node within our **Realtime Database**.

Here's where things get really weird. We have both a `DEV` and `PROD` project for our client. When this function is deployed and running in DEV, it works with no issues! But when in PROD, it only works about 70% of the time (that is a rough guess). When I say it "only works sometimes", the function logs are printing out `Function execution took 1556ms, finished with status: 'ok'` - but the updating does not always occur.

Node version is `v12.16.2`, npm version is `6.14.4`

Is there something specific that we need to set in regards to the timeout or memory usage? It is just bizarre that it works with no issues in one Firebase project but not the other.

Please advise!! Any help is great, as our client processes hundreds of transactions a night. I can show some code if necessary, just would like to protect our client's code if at all possible...

Comment: Do you see anything in the Cloud Functions logs when the database fails to be updated?  Are there any errors in the Cloud Functions logs at all?  Have you reviewed the limitations of Cloud Functions, specifically the time limits, to see if that might be occurring with your PROD environment (real data, bigger sizes, etc.)?  https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

Comment: @mobiGeek, there are no errors in the logs. It just prints out the successful execution message displayed above. 

How could I check to see if the quota limit is being hit? As far as I know, there’s no errors being reported that we are exceeding any sort of memory/time limit. Maybe it’s timing out?

Comment: Can you put a simple `console.log("STARTING")` at the start of your function and re-deploy, just to be sure you are running "the latest" and see that *something* is getting logged?  Are there other `console.log()` statements in your code that you expect to be seeing output but aren't?

Comment: @mobiGeek we have a console.log() statement already in there. It is definitely running and getting logged. It just seems like it is timing out or something. It has worked successfully for 7 days in a row now, but last night went right back to the issues described above...

Comment: If there are no errors in the logs, then I would assume this is not about hitting limits or something.  They'd likely lead to exceptions being thrown and thus get logged.

Unless...you are doing try/catch around code that is failing and quashing the error?